# Media query hide/show a table?

Tags: javascript, media-queries

How can I toggle between hide/show on a table (id=firsttable) with a Media Query with JavaScript? My code is:

```
    function myFunction(r) {
        var q = document.getElementById('firsttable');
        if (r.matches) {
                q.style.display = 'none';
            } else {
                q.style.display = 'block';
            }
        }
    var r = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 700px)")
    myFunction(r) 
    r.addListener(myFunction)
```

Comment: Why not using resize event?

Comment: Here you go https://jsfiddle.net/u0596q4e/4/, just adapt

Comment: Thank you executable works great.

Comment: @executable could you please post this as an answer instead of a comment?

Answer (score 0):

As @executable responded in comments:

```js
window.onresize = function(event) {
 var w = window.innerWidth;
  if(w > 700){
   document.getElementById('text').style.display = 'block';
  }else{
    document.getElementById('text').style.display = 'none';
    }
};
```

```html
<span id="text">Lorum</span>
```